# efficiency of a stirling engine with spring

Tags: thermodynamics

I have used the concept of stirling engine with a spring instead of any gas to make an engine....i want to calculate the efficiency of it...here's a pic:
[image]

Comment: What is efficiency that you want calculate.
Efficiency to compress the springs or Efficiency to rotate the disk?

Comment: efficiency to rotate the disk...

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of engine is defined as ratio of the useful work done to the heat provided:

$\epsilon=\frac{work done}{heat \space absorbed}=\frac{Q_2-Q_1}{Q_1}$

Notice that the work done relates to the power delivered at the clutch or at the driveshaft.
This means the friction and other losses are subtracted from the work done by thermodynamic expansion. Thus an engine not delivering any work to the outside environment has zero efficiency.

Also, note that  engines for which efficiency is defined in this way are compbustion engines, or at least require a gas with expansion contraction phases that can exchange heat (such as a carnot engine).

In your case you engine operates at a constant temperature, you only transform the elastic energy of the springs into work. I asume you replace the springs on every sycle by compressed ones, otherwise the machine will not have any power source. In this case you could define a new kind of efficiency, different to that of combustion engines, but that wtill makes sense.

For instace, you can define

$$\epsilon=\frac{work\space done}{elastic \space energy \space stored \space in \space the \space springs}$$